# How to display MSRP / RRP on product page

Tags: magento-1.9, price

I'm looking to display the value I have set in "Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price" on the product page.

I was hoping it was going to be as simple case of adding something like the following to view.phtml, unfortunately it doesn't seem to be.

```
<?php echo $this->getMSRPPriceHtml($_product); ?>
```

Comment: Please mark an answer as correct if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following in `price.phtml`:-

```
<?php $_msrpPrice = $this->helper('core')->currency($_product->getMsrp(),true,true) ?>
```

Then output with:-

```
<?php echo $_msrpPrice ?>
```

This of course, providing your `view.phtml` echo's `$this->getPriceHtml($_product);`

Answer (score 1):

Just paste the below code..It worked for me.

```
echo $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getMsrp());
```