# MSRP does not show up product and list page

Tags: magento-1.9, msrp

Even though there is a value for MSRP (Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price), the value does not show up on neither the product page or category listing page. Obviously it would be desired to show store price and MSRP crossed out!

Is there a setting in admin to make it get displayed?

[image]

Comment: try this : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65166/how-to-display-msrp-rrp-on-product-page

Comment: you may need https://siven76.com/2013/03/08/magento-display-manufacturers-suggested-retail-price/

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get your MSRP is to modify the catalog/product/view.phtml.
As normal, do not edit the one in the base/default or rwd/default.
Instead you need to create  your own copy.  This way you keep the core files in tact.  Once you do, you can add your html, as the above links suggest.  So, there is nothing you can do via the admin to make it show up using out of the box templates.

Comment: The only way to get the line through the price using out of the box features is to set a special price.  Then you get the line through without having to modify any code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks the qst is too old. But I will answer it anyway.

By default I don't think MSRP shows up. From your question I think you are asking more of sale price and RRP.

**If you enter your MSRP price in `Price` field, which is $119 and then $89 in `Special Price` field, then it will cross the $119.**

If you still want to show MSRP, then you will need to edit the template file.

In your view.phtml file, add this:

```
echo $this->helper('core')->currency($_product->getMsrp(),true,true);
```